# Git hook that prevent pushing if there is sonar issues on modified files

Tags: git, githooks, sonarqube-scan

I am wondering if there is a git hook that prevent pushing to origin if there is sonar issues on modified files ?

Comment: I wrote one. It's not perfect, and it's based on a tool that is no longer supported. It's somewhat working for now, but it might stop working at some point. https://github.com/janosgyerik/sonarlint-git-hooks

Comment: Great Job, thank you!